# "Combine" logical expression and return the subexpressions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, compiler-construction, logical-operators, jison

I need to write an algorithm that takes a logical expression as input, combines its operators and returns the subexpressions.

Some examples of what I need:

> foo -> ["foo"]
>
> foo bar -> ["foo bar"]
>
> foo bar OR baz -> ["foo bar", "baz"]
>
> foo bar (baz OR zim) OR zum -> ["foo bar baz", "foo bar zim", "zum"]
>
> foo bar ("baz bets" OR zim) OR zum -> ["foo bar baz bets", "foo bar zim", "zum"]
>
> (foo OR bar) (baz OR zim) -> ["foo baz", "foo zim", "bar baz", "bar zim"]

I already have a lexical and syntactycal analyzer for the logical expreesions (used JISON to define the grammar and generate the parser).
Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: You could build a Finite Automata (Deterministic or Non-Deterministic) and then run through all the options.

Comment: could you post the output of your analyzer, applied to your examples?